# How hard is it to find the first layer of this basic $\mathbb{Z}_p$-extension?

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, galois-theory, iwasawa-theory

$\DeclareMathOperator\Gal{Gal}$Let $p$ be a prime number and $\zeta_{p^n}$ be a primitive $p^n$-th root of unity.  We know that there is a unique subfield $\mathbb{Q}_1$ of $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{p^2})$ such that $[\mathbb{Q}_1:\mathbb{Q}]=p$ (the first layer of the cyclotomic $\mathbb{Z}_p$-extension of $\mathbb{Q}$).

Here are some basic things I know about $\mathbb{Q}_1$:

1. Since $[\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{p^2}):\mathbb{Q}]=p(p-1)$ and $\Gal(\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{p^2})/\mathbb{Q})$ is cyclic we know that $\mathbb{Q}_1$ is contained in the maximal real subfield $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{p^2})^+$ of $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{p^2})$.
2. Since $p$ is prime, we have that $\mathbb{Q}_1$ contains no other subfields.
3. We know that $p$ is totally ramified in $\mathbb{Q}_1$.

If $k$ is an imaginary quadratic field such that the discriminant $m$ of $k$ is co-prime to $p$, then the first layer $k_1$ of the cyclotomic $\mathbb{Z}_p$-extension of $k$ is the compositum $k\mathbb{Q}_1$ (this is also true for $k_n$ and $k\mathbb{Q}_n$).

Let $\lambda = \lambda_p$ be Iwasawa's lambda invariant for the cyclotomic $\mathbb{Z}_p$-extension $k \subseteq k_1 \subseteq k_2 \dots k_{\infty}$, and $A(k_n)$ be the $p$-part of the class group of $k_n$.

In [On small Iwasawa invariants and imaginary quadratic fields](https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1991-112-03/S0002-9939-1991-1057961-4), Sands has shown that Iwasawa's Theorem usually kicks in at an early stage for Imaginary quadratic fields.  In particular, if $\lambda < p-1$, then $\lvert A(k_1)\rvert = \lvert A(k)\rvert p^{\lambda}$.  So, it seems to me if we know enough about $k_1$, we may have a shot at knowing about $\lambda$ (provided we know about $A(k)$ and $A(k_1)$, which is another question altogether).  But from the above, I feel that knowing about $\mathbb{Q}_1$ in general might be worthwhile since again $k_1 = k\mathbb{Q}_1$.

After trying to work out a few examples, it seems pretty difficult in general to figure out the first what the first layer $\mathbb{Q}_1$ is.

Some questions I have:

1. Have people thought about this before?
2. Is there anything in the literature that may help with this?
3. Are there any other obvious properties about $\mathbb{Q}_1$ that I've overlooked?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: One way to generate this field explicitly is to use the polynomial
whose roots are $\sum_{n \in c} \zeta_{p^2}^n$ where $c$ ranges over
the $p$ cosets of ${(\mathbb{Z}/p^2\mathbb{Z})^\times}^p$ in
$(\mathbb{Z}/p^2\mathbb{Z})^\times$.  For $p=3,5,7,11$ this gives
$x^3-x+1$ (for $\zeta_9^n + \zeta_9^{-n}$), 
$x^5 - 10x^3 - 5x^2 + 10x - 1$,
$x^7 - 7x^6 + 49x^4 - 98x^2 - 49x + 7$, and
$x^{11}-11x^{10}+363x^8-1089x^7-1089x^6+6413x^5+242x^4-11616x^3-2178x^2+6534x+2673$.

Comment: @NoamD.Elkies  Does this come from Kummer theory?  Or am I totally off?

Comment: typo: $x^3-3x+1$

Comment: By the way, one can also compute anticyclotomic ones : http://www.numdam.org/item/CM_1976__32_2_157_0/?source=CM_1975__30_3_259_0 by Carroll and Kisilevsky and higher layers for $p=3$ in https://arxiv.org/abs/1806.10473. Though that was not asked.

Comment: @ChrisWuthrich Thanks for pointing me towards the paper.

Comment: @NoamD.Elkies  Or is it more this:  Gal$(\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{p^2})^+/\mathbb{Q}_1) \cong$ Gal$(\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{p})/\mathbb{Q}) /\langle \tau \rangle$ where $\tau$ is complex conjugation.  So I think the elements you mentioned above are fixed by these automorphisms (I'll check all the details).

Answer (score 0):

Let $p$ be a prime number and let $\mathbb{Q}_{n}$ be the $n$th layer of the cyclotomic $\mathbb{Z}_{p}$-extension of $\mathbb{Q}$. Then $A(\mathbb{Q}_{n})$, the $p$-part of the class group of $\mathbb{Q}_{n}$, is trivial for all $n$. (In particular, the $\lambda$ and $\mu$ invariants of the cyclotomic $\mathbb{Z}_p$-extension of $\mathbb{Q}$ are both zero.)

This follows from Theorem 10.4(b) in Washington's "Introduction to cyclotomic fields" (second edition). Alternatively, see Proposition 1.1.4 in Ralph Greenberg's online book available here: [https://sites.math.washington.edu/~greenber/book.pdf](https://sites.math.washington.edu/%7Egreenber/book.pdf)

So my feeling is that explicit knowledge of $\mathbb{Q}_{1}$ doesn't really help with the problem you're interested in. Of course, I'd be interested to know what's going on if this intuition turns out to be incorrect.

Comment: My real aim was to find the initial layer of an imaginary quadratic field $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-m})$, so I wanted to find $\mathbb{Q}_1$ and then just adjoin $\sqrt{-m}$.

Comment: Okay, but I'm not clear in what sense you want to "find" $\mathbb{Q}_{1}$. Something along the lines of Noam's comment, or in some other sense?

Comment: I wanted to get a better picture of what $\mathbb{Q}_1$ is like, so Noam's comment is more or less what I was looking for.